# Appending to a list in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a table which pulls a the value and if there is any error message in that column I need to give a HARD CODED message saying "Error is found"

```
// Property 
Public partial Class section: IXmlserializable
public List<string> ErrorMessage {get, set}

if(ErrorMessage != null && ErrorMessage.Count > 0)
    Writer.WriteElement("Notifications")

Writer.WriteEndElement();

// I call this in my Body of the Page
Datatable dt = this.GetErrorMessage(rountingcode, BookKey,userobject)

if(dt != null dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Book.ErrorMessage.add(dt.Rows[0]["ErrorColumn"].ToString());
}

// Idea is to add from the Book to its SECTION property ErrorMessage
if(Book.ErrorMessage!= null && Book.ErrorMessage.Count>0 )
// INITIALIZE 

sec.ErrorMessage = new List<string>();
// IF the Book does contain any Error message that we pulled from the table
// Display HARD coded message
sec.ErrorMessage.Add("Hey Buddy you have a error in the BODY ") 
}
```

Now what if i have some other ERROR because in my Header Book.ErrorMessage from a different PROC which is using the same PROPERTY ErrorMessage which has the STRING ("Hey Buddy you have a error in the HEADER") pulled from some other dataTable for HEADER Error

So when it comes to the condition

```
if(dt != null dt.Rows.Count > 0 )  // It want go inside
```

BUT

```
if(Book.ErrorMessage!= null && Book.ErrorMessage.Count>0)
// Will go here
// As it is using the same Property ErrorMessage for to get the HEADER 
//Error.
```

Is there any way to append it as we can show both the ErrorMessage as of now it is always overriding.

```
<Notification>
Hey Buddy you have a error in the BODY   
Hey Buddy you have a error in the HEADER</Notification>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want the output to be. Can you clarify with a concrete example? Also, check your code. For example, you have `if (dt != null dt.Rows.Count > 0)`. I think you're missing an `&&` there in both places. And it wouldn't hurt to indent your code.

Comment: Yes you are right but you got the idea .. It want go in that loop as my Datatable has no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using a SQL query by pulling a column that holds the error list.If the columns has 1 row as error it should retrieve the value using a datatable. I queried the data table using a linq query and added to the list. Thank you all for all your help